# Flutter - Texts I put in Wrap do not stand side by side

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a code like this:

```
  AnimatedOpacity(
    opacity: _usefulInterfaceContent ? 1 : 0,
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7),
      child: Wrap(
        direction: Axis.horizontal,
        children: [
          InkWell(
            child: Text("Zoro ", textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19, color: Colors.white, fontFamily: "Montserrat")), // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            onTap: () {
              Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
                setState(() {
                  AssetsAudioPlayer.newPlayer().open(
                    Audio("assets/audios/ZoroEasterEggSound.mp3"),
                    autoStart: true,
                    showNotification: true,
                  );
                  ezAnimation = EzAnimation(200.0, 230.0, const Duration(milliseconds: 1500), curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn, reverseCurve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn);
                  ezAnimation.start();
                });
              });
              Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 1500), () {
                setState(() {
                  ezAnimation = EzAnimation(230.0, 200.0, const Duration(milliseconds: 1500), curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn, reverseCurve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn);
                  ezAnimation.start();
                });
              });
            },
          ),
          Text("gibi kaybolmaman için rehberin olacağız! Basit ve özelleştirilebilir bir arayüz ile birlikte özgürlüğünüzün tadını çıkarın! ⚙️ ", textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19, color: Colors.white, fontFamily: "Montserrat")), // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        ],
      ),
```

As you can see, there are two `Text` in `Wrap`. But these two `Text`s do not stand side by side. It looks like this:

[image]

`Text` with "Zoro" has moved up a bit. How can I solve this problem? I want to see both `Text`s as combined paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the amount of text within the second `Text` widget, it takes up the full width of the view, and therefore is pushed to the next line.

If I understand your goal, you should be able to accomplish what you want with `RichText` instead of `Wrap`:

```dart
  RichText(
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    text: TextSpan(children: [
      TextSpan(
        text: "Zoro ",
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 19,
          color: Colors.white,
          fontFamily: "Montserrat",
        ),
        recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
          ..onTap = () {
            Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
              setState(() {
                AssetsAudioPlayer.newPlayer().open(
                  Audio("assets/audios/ZoroEasterEggSound.mp3"),
                  autoStart: true,
                  showNotification: true,
                );
                ezAnimation = EzAnimation(
                    200.0, 230.0, const Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
                    curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                    reverseCurve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn);
                ezAnimation.start();
              });
            });
            Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 1500), () {
              setState(() {
                ezAnimation = EzAnimation(
                    230.0, 200.0, const Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
                    curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                    reverseCurve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn);
                ezAnimation.start();
              });
            });
          },
      ),
      TextSpan(
        text:
            "gibi kaybolmaman için rehberin olacağız! Basit ve özelleştirilebilir bir arayüz ile birlikte özgürlüğünüzün tadını çıkarın! ⚙️ ",
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 19,
          color: Colors.white,
          fontFamily: "Montserrat",
        ),
      )
    ]),
  )
```

If, on the other hand, you don't exactly want to combine the texts, but just have the second paragraph sit next to the "Zoro " text, you can simply use a `Row`:

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    InkWell(
      // Your "Zoro " text widget, etc.
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Text(
        "... The remaining text",
        style: // Your style
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

*note: I may have not fully understood your question correctly.*

The problem is that you're using the `Wrap()` widget, what this widget does is that if there's not enough space to fit all children in the main axis, it will *wrap to the next line*. That's exactly what's happening here.
From the documentation:

> ...If there is not enough space to fit the child, Wrap creates a new
> run adjacent to the existing children in the cross axis.

If you run your code in Chrome you will see, that when I open a *maximized* window, then the text is together:

[image]

However, once I minimize the window, then the text `Wrap`s:

[image]

So, don't use the `Wrap()` widget.